# return to normal mode when the window loses focus

Tags: normal-mode

Is it possible to make Vim automatically exit whatever mode it's in and return to normal mode when the terminal window loses focus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd FocusLost * call feedkeys("\<esc>")
```

This essentially means "If we lose focus (`autocmd FocusLost`) on any filetype (`*`), then type an escape key as if I pressed it (`call feedkeys("\<esc>"`)

Recommended reading: [`:help FocusLost`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FocusLost) and [`:help autocommand`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)

As Statox pointed out in the comments, this will only work for GVim, and certain terminals.

Comment: this didn't work

Comment: If I may point it out, the doc says `Only for the GUI version and a few console versions where this can be detected.` so in some cases this might not work.

Comment: @ewok What OS and terminal are you using?

Comment: Windows7, Cygwin. but I'm looking for a cross-platform solution I can use anywhere

Comment: @ewok - a cross platform solution is impossible.  Vim runs on raw `tty`'s and inside things like `screen` and `tmux`.  All these three options have no access to anything like a focus, by design.